# bin/dev: 8: exec: foreman: not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, esbuild, jsbundling-rails

Hello I am currently following a tutorial in order to connect react to my rails app that uses https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails and went with esbuild, however when I run bin/dev in my terminal I get the above error any help is appreciated as this is my first time trying to use react along with a rails app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) gem. You can install it in the terminal with this command:

```
gem install foreman
```

From foreman's github page:

> Ruby users should take care not to install foreman in their project's Gemfile. See this [wiki article](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/wiki/Don%27t-Bundle-Foreman) for more details.